# can we use odds ratio for the risk estimation in support vector machine regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, odds-ratio, supervised-learning

I want to compare the logistic regression model and support vector machine regression. odds ratio is used in logistic regression. can we use odds ratio in support vector machine regression.???

Answer (score 0):

If you would replace the maximum margin criterion of SVMs with the log-odds method of logistic regression, you would end up with kernel logistic regression. Applying the kernel mechanism to known regression and classification methods has first (I think) been studied in [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/r2/jaakkola99a/jaakkola99a.pdf).